# Given two paid roads from point x to point y, find the cheapest road

Tags: arrays, algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

**Given:** Two roads, L and R, they both start from point x and end in point y.

They're both paid roads, and they have n paid points in the road l1,l2,..,ln on the L road and r1,r2,...rn on the R road, which you have to pay when you cross that point.

If you want to keep driving to point y from R road instead of L (or from road L instead of R), you have to pay the changing road fee(but not the paid point).Meaning, If you leave in point i, you don't have to pay for the point li or ri, but just the changing road fee, and then you continue to the i+1 point in the new road you're in (R or L) - and you have to paid that l(i+1) or r(i+1). points of changing road fee are defined by s1,s2,...sn.

**EXAMPLE:** If I'm in point 3 in road R and I choose to keep driving to point y from road L, I just pay s3 (and not r3), and then I pay l4 too.

**Question:** Solve this in DP that finds the cheapest way from x to y with the best time complexity.

I come up with a solution which I believe won't work all the time, and I hope you can help me construct a better working one.

**Define:** Graph G, 2n vertices, edges are (li, li+1), (li, ri), and even 3n vertices because of (ri,ri+1). Array of size n called x. so x[i] will hold the value of the lowest cost route on up to index i. We will fill the array from the n to 1. We'll init the values of the array with zero. And the formula be as followed. A[i] = min { A[i+1] + xi, A[i+1] + si + x_(i+1)] }. In the end, we return A[1].

I believe this fails sometimes, If it's true, I would love to get some help on changing it to work properly or finding another algorithm that will get this job done.

Comment: There seems to be some inconsistency in your notation and explanation: Do you store the cost of the lowest cost route in x[i] or A[i]? Why do you need to add x_(i+1) when you stated that changing roads incurs only the changing road fee? If you stick with your first explanation, then when changing from R to L at point i, you would pay si, then r_(i+1) and then r_(i+1) again?

Comment: I just noticed I wrote A[i] which isn't defined. You're right about that part. About the last question, If I want to change roads, I will pay si, and then R(i+1) if it's from L to R, otherwise L(i+1), just once. @TobiasRibizel

Comment: Let's say I start at road R and switch at point 3. Then my journey would be r1 r2 r3 l4 l5 .... What would be the cost of this path? Is it 1) r1+r2+s3+l4+l5 because after switching we don't need to pay the fee or 2) r1+r2+s3+l3+l4+l5 because after switching, we still pass l3 and need to pay the fee there or 3) r1+r2+(s3+l4)+l4+l5 because after passing l4, I would have to pay the fee there, regardless if I came from l3 or r3. It sounds like you're describing 3), but I'm suspecting you actually want 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there are some unclear points about your formulation, I'll post my solution anyways and add clarification if necessary.

### Graph theoretic approach

The transformation you do to construct you 2n vertex graph is definitely sensible, since your problem becomes a shortest path problem.

If you assign the cost *road fee at ri* to edges `(ri, r(i+1))` or *road fee at li* to edges `(li, l(i+1))` and *road switch fee si* to edges `(ri,l(i+1))` or `(li,r(i+1))`, a shortest path from x to y is also a cheapest path in your model.

### Dynamic programming formulation

Because of the structure of the graph, you don't need a shortest path algorithm like Dijkstra, a simpler solution similar to the one you proposed should suffice. However when storing your array x, you have no way of determining if the optimal solution to get to a certain position i should end on road R or L.

A simple way to resolve this issue would be to store the shortest way for every paid point ri and li, i.e. store two arrays AR and AL where AR[i]  is the optimal cost to get to ri (and AL[i] for li)

A simple DP formulation would be

```
AR[1] = AL[1] = 0 // We don't need to pay at the start
// either stay on the road or switch the road and pay changing fee:
AR[i + 1] = min(AR[i] + fee at ri, AL[i] + changing fee si)
AL[i + 1] = min(AL[i] + fee at li, AR[i] + changing fee si)
```

and compute the minimal cost by taking the minimum of AR[n + 1] and AL[n + 1]. To get the actual road, simply backtrack which choices were taken at every `min` computation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I suspect the formula could be changed to `AR[i + 1] = min(AR[i] + r(i+1), AL[i] + changing fee si + (L_i+1))`, and changed accordingly in `AL`.

Comment: This sounds like an off-by-one issue: In your model, the first fee at r1 is never paid, while in my model, the last fee at rn is never paid. I guess the simplest solution would be to add final nodes r(n+1) and l(n+1) with fee 0 and take their solutions.

Comment: Or perhaps, run until n-1 ?

Comment: What about the edges (li,li+1), and (li,ri+1)? I need to add them too to my graph.

Comment: I added them to the description. Still you need to watch out for off-by-one errors, I think reading the result from index n + 1 is the simplest solution, actually you don't need to ad any additional road fees, since r(n+1) and l(n+1) are never explicitly considered.

Comment: I noticed. I believe our answer satisfies the requirements, meaning this algorithm isn't greedy. Thanks for your time Tobias.